# Find duplicate files selected in FileDialog

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating a function that finds for duplicate files selected with **FileDialog**, this is what I did:

Since the **Collection** FileDialogSelectedItems is read-only I search for a function to get a hash and converted the collection to an **Array**

```
Dim FilesArray(), ArraySHA(), FilteredArray() as String 
set fdg = Application.FileDialog(3)

With fdg
.....
If .show = -1 then
   ReDim ArraySHA(fdg.SelectedItems.Count)
   For i = 1 to fdg.SelectedItems.Count
      ArraySHA(i) = FileToSHA256(fdg.SelectedItems.Item(i)) '' New array with hashes
   Next i
```

Then I used another function to filter duplicates in the ArraySHA

```
   FilteredArray = FilterWords(ArraySHA)
```

Now I have an array with the unique hashes, but I need to have the selectedItems (filepaths) so I can import them without duplicates.

Thank you very much

---

**Edit**: I created a dictionary based on the SelectedItems Collection, adding each item only if it is not already there

```
    For i = 1 To fdg.SelectedItems.Count
        SHA = FileToSHA256(fdg.SelectedItems.Item(i))
        If Not dict.Exists(SHA) Then
                dict.Add SHA, fdg.SelectedItems.Item(i)
        End if
    Next i
```

Now I have the hashes that correspond to only one file, which is its key value

```
   For Each key In dict.keys
        UniqueValue = dict(key)
        '
        'do something with each unique value (which is the filepath)
        '
   Next key
```

Comment: Could a dictionary help? BTW, `Dim FilesArray(), ArraySHA(), FilteredArray() as String ` will only declare `FilteredArray()` as an array of strings.

Comment: I don't get, in which cases a filepicker-dialog should return duplicates, but each `SelectedItems(i)` includes the full path.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think the OP is talking about the filenames and not the complete path.

Comment: If the path is always the same then you can't have duplicates or multiple entries , right! But if you have different paths the filename could be the same. I think the OP has to clarify.

Comment: Ah, I see you can't select files from different paths with the code above. So, the OP has to clarify what the problem is.

Comment: How would you define 'duplicate files'? what are the parameters you would send to some `AreDuplicateFiles (FileA, FileB) As Boolean` function? would these be file path `String`s? file `Object`s? Seems to me you should begin by defining this function, then see how to convert data from `fdg` to your desired data structure.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I edited my question to make it more clear and went with a Dictionary with "If not Dict.Exists(SHA) then..."

Comment: I still don't get the reason for all this. Did you EVER get ANY duplicate entry in your returned list of `FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).SelectedItems`? What operating system do you have, allowing duplicate filenames?

Comment: Asger, I may not have been clear, sorry, I meant duplicate files, not filenames. The user chooses txt files to import. Those files may have the same content but with different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a dictionary based on the SelectedItems Collection, adding each item only if it is not already there

```
    For i = 1 To fdg.SelectedItems.Count
        SHA = FileToSHA256(fdg.SelectedItems.Item(i))
        If Not dict.Exists(SHA) Then
                dict.Add SHA, fdg.SelectedItems.Item(i)
        End if
    Next i
```

Now I have the hashes that correspond to only one file, which is its key value

```
   For Each key In dict.keys
        UniqueValue = dict(key)
        '
        'do something with each unique value (which is the filepath)
        '
   Next key
```